# Appropriate way to merge classes

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

How can I merge inner container + row d-flex classes into the first class that contains the ID? I am getting an error at the end that a  tag is missing, even though I have added it.

> ```
> <div id="page" class="container p-0 mt-md-4 mt-0 border-secondary rounded-3 border-opacity-50">
>     <div class="inner container p-2 p-md-4">
>         <div class="row d-flex align-items-center">
>             <div class="col-sm-4">
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Do you think so?

```
    <!-- id page -->
    <div id="page" class="container p-0 mt-md-4 mt-0 border-secondary rounded-3 border-opacity-50">
        <!-- inner container -->
        <div class="inner container p-2 p-md-4">
            <!-- row d-flex -->
            <div class="row d-flex align-items-center">
                <!-- col -->
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

What do you mean **merge** if not like that?